# Problems Using Class Library - Need to include directory of files

Tags: php

I'm trying to use the following library, but am having SO many problems!
v1.1.1  https://github.com/triplepoint/php-units-of-measure/releases

```
<?php
require './PhpUnitsOfMeasure/PhysicalQuantity.php';
require './PhpUnitsOfMeasure/UnitOfMeasureInterface.php';
require './PhpUnitsOfMeasure/UnitOfMeasure.php';
require './PhpUnitsOfMeasure/PhysicalQuantity/Length.php';

$height = new Length(6.16, 'feet');
echo $height->toUnit('m');

?>
```

I'm getting: Fatal error: Class 'Length' not found

I'm sure this is such a stupid question, but I have been banging my head against the wall and I just want it to work!  Please help!

Comment: Its [introduction](https://github.com/triplepoint/php-units-of-measure) clearly indicate that the class is inside its own [namespace](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php) (which is very reasonable, as to avoid name collision).

Comment: @Passerby Thanks so much for taking the time to point me in the right direction.  It was not clear to me from that introduction (which I DID read, multiple times) that it was inside its own namespace, so your comment was exceedingly helpful.  I know that I have a lot to learn!